# Timer stops running after a while

Tags: android, timer

I have written a small programm which constantly opens a certain website with a timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();          
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
          myview.loadUrl(readFromFile());
      }
    }, 10000, 180000);
```

But the problem with this is that it stop running after a certain amount of time (like 1 or 2 weeks). I was thinking of some sort of cache overflow with too high numbers.
Can i change this code, so that my timer runs consistant without stopping after some time?
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Timers run in threads that are separate from the main UI thread, and as a result any exceptions will simply cause the thread to stop. The problem is likely due to the thread encountering an exception.

In order to debug this problem, I would suggest you try to catch and log this exception. You can do this by registering a default exception handler for the application. [This article](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-handling-the-unexpected/) gives a pretty good explanation on how to do this.

Let me know how the debugging goes, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i have a question about logging: The site you have linked me isnt showing how to log the expectation. It just explains how to create a log but not how to save it :c

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't sure if you needed that! Personally, I use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), it is pretty easy to setup (lots of tutorials around such as [this one](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)), and also supports sending crash logs by email or logging them to a server (slightly more complicated).